# Collapsing duplicate foreign key values in Django migrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have a Django app that I need to perform a migration on.  Here's a representational schema of what I need to modify:

```
class A(Model):
    c = ForeignKey(C)
    ...

class B(Model):
    c = ForeignKey(C)
    ...

class C(Model):
    x = CharField()
    y = CharField()
    z = CharField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('x', 'y', 'z'),)
```

`z` is no longer relevant to the uniqueness of the foreign key `C`.  So I am going to drop the field `z` and change the unique requirement to just `x` and `y`.

But first I need to do a data migration that drops the upcoming duplicate entries, *and* I need to fix up all of the ForeignKeys to point to that single consolidated entry.

I'm looking if there is a better way than what I'll outline in my answer below.  I'm not entirely satisfied with my answer as it doesn't have any safeguards of dropping a foreign key that is still in use -- other than the algorithm itself.  (Like, what if there is also another foreign key relationship to `C` I overlooked.)

(Django 1.7 & Postgres)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the steps that seem the most straight forward:

- Make a migration to drop `z` and the `unique_together` constraint.
- Make a data migration

  - For each `A` object find the `c` object with the smallest `id` and reassign `A.c` to that object.
  - For each `B` object find the `c` object with the smallest `id` and reassign `B.c` to that object.
  - Get a list of all `C`'s and a list of all `C`'s referenced by `A` and `B`, subtract the sets and `delete()` the remainder.
- Make a migration to reinstate the `unique_together`.